Brazilian Crime Action TV Series w rave reviews & was talked about in Western Media?

I vaguely remember it having rave reviews & being talked about in press / TV / online media sometime in last 5-10 years. 
The clips in the article showed a hard hitting Crime Action Drama centered on Favelas, Drugs etc. in a major Brazilian City - mostly I think it was Rio, maybe Sao Paulo as well?  

In my googling around I found 9mm, Sao Paulo, but not sure if it's that one. 
I could've sworn it was Rio based, but I barely had a glimpse of it


I wish I could find that article / thing on TV that talked about. 

Probably you're thinking of City of Men (or in the original Portuguese, Cidade dos Homens) - 2002-05 TV spin-off of the critically acclaimed 2002 film City of God. 
 
They're both highly regarded Brazilian dramas set in a notorious Rio favela (slum), following children caught up in drugs-related violence and crime. It's possible your question mixes up things you've heard about both the film and the series:

City of God, the 2002 film, definitely matches your description in being very hard-hitting and critically acclaimed worldwide. It's currently ranked #21 in IMDB's list of top-ranking films of all time at time of writing, one place behind Star Wars, just above Se7en and Silence of the Lambs.
City of Men, the 2002-05 TV series, is lighter, more comedic, based loosely on telenovellas (soap operas), but with the same dark themes. It's quite critically acclaimed, but not to the same extent as the first film.

In this original variation on the Latin American telenovela (slow, emotional soap), life in Rio de Janeiro, the Brazilian big city jungle, is told in short, fast alternating scenes from the viewpoints of two sets of characters, all youngsters, but from both sides of unequal life

To add to the confusion, there's also a 2007 film City of Men, by the same people, which has a good-but-not-great rating of 7.7, and is more like City of God in being darker with less comic elements
There's also a 2013 documentary, City of God : 10 Years Later, which followed up on the lives of the young actors in the first film, many of whom were real favela kids themselves.


Thanks. I will check it out. I think it was more like a CSI/ Task force/ Special Police focused on Crime in Drugs/ Favelas kind of thing. I will check out your suggestion and keep looking :) Muito Obrigado :)

Maybe is this movie:
Tropa de Elite / Elite Squad

1997, Captain Nascimento has to find a substitute for his occupation while trying to take down drug dealers and criminals before the Pope comes to Rio de Janeiro, Brazil.

